# Handling PointerEntered and PointerReleased but passing Click/Tap to parent element

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a Grid and inside the grid, I have Buttons. I need PointerEntered and PointerReleased events as I need to track which buttons are hovered. The problem is that, I need my Grid to handle the click events. Even though I don't have a click/tap/press handler for the button, my button captures the click and doesn't bubble it up to its parent (Grid). If I disable the button by settin IsEnabled to false, the click event is bubbled up to the Grid correctly, but then PointerEntered and PointerReleased events aren't fired, which I need to handle on the button. How can I handle enter/release events on the button and at the same time, pass the click event to its parent? I need my Grid to go onto "clicked" state as I also listen for the PointerReleased event on it. If click doesn't fire, released doesn't fire even if I do release the mouse button when on the Grid.

Thanks,
Can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using AddHandler to attach a click event to grid and see if it works for you. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.addhandler.aspx
Remember to remove the event using RemoveHandler when done.

Comment: that worked like a charm. don't understand why I need to do it explicitly, but anyway, thanks :)

Comment: Sometimes other controls consume it and events are not bubbled up in the chain :). So AddHandler is a way to listen to those kind of events.

Comment: Assuming you set the handledEventsToo param to true. That is the key.